# Use multiple SSDs for single geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, geth-debugging

I am setting up a Geth archive node, and it take a lot of space, I have a few SSDs (each 1 tb), I want to configure get in a way that when SSD1 is full it should automatically continue storing new data into SSD2 and so on. Any help?